# Where does "pay through the nose" originate?

Tags: word-usage

Where does the saying  " pay through the nose" originate?

Comment: https://www.google.nl/search?q=pay+through+the+nose+etymology

Answer (score 0):

Seems an Irishman is perfectly suited for this one!

It's from the time when the Vikings invaded Ireland, and charged taxes on the local Irish people. There's two supposed reasons what the nose tax was - either a tax calculated by counting the number of noses in a region, or else that failure to pay the tax would result in having your nose cut off.

[Source.](http://www.hindu.com/edu/2007/09/25/stories/2007092550151504.htm)

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent essay on the phrase [here](http://blog.oup.com/2010/10/pay-through-the-nose/). He favours a nautical term for paying out a cable.